# How to create Ruby repl in the browser

Tags: ruby, browser, sinatra, read-eval-print-loop

Hi thanks for taking a look at my question. I'm trying to create a site with a Sinatra server that will allow users to run ruby code in the browser similar to what you see with repl.it, code academy, etc.

Is there a gem/library or anything out there can can handle the interpreter? If I need to create one myself, how can I do this without evaluating the code in the server? (seems dangerous)

Any advice is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use repl.it's API https://repl.it/api 
Should be very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Kernel#eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to run code from the string (user's input). Remember that it is not safe to execute some random code directly in your production environment.